# How to add buttons

Tags: python, html, image, file

I am viewing images and files side by side for that I need next and previous button because each time I don't want to click 1,2,3,4... instead of this if I gave next means it should open next image and file and if I give previous means it should open previous image and file

Comment: So you need an image widget on the left and text widget for json file on the right. Below them are the two buttons previous and next.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample photo viewer code. It reads image and json files in the image folder, save it to a list, and use this list in the app.

There is a session state variable called `idx` used to track the next and previous.

```
"""Images are taken from https://unsplash.com/
"""


import json
import os

import streamlit as st


st.set_page_config(
    page_title="Photo viewer",
    page_icon="",
    layout="centered",
    initial_sidebar_state="expanded",
)


# Track an index for image, prev and next buttons.
if 'idx' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.idx = 0


def get_image_files():
    """Images and json files are in image folder,"""
    file_paths = []
    image_path = './image'
    for p in os.listdir(image_path):
        if p.endswith('.jpg'):
            file_paths.append(f'./image/{p}')

    return file_paths


def view_next():
    """Update idx, reset to zero if index is above max"""
    photos = get_image_files()
    next_index = st.session_state.idx + 1
    if next_index >= len(photos):
        next_index = 0
    st.session_state.idx = next_index


def view_previous():
    """Update idx, reset to max if index is below zero"""
    photos = get_image_files()
    prev_index = st.session_state.idx - 1
    if prev_index < 0:
        prev_index = len(photos) - 1
    st.session_state.idx = prev_index


def main():
    photos = get_image_files()

    # Center the header.
    col_h = st.columns([1, 3])
    with col_h[1]:
        st.header('Streamlit Photo Viewer')

    with st.container():
        col_1 = st.columns([1, 1])

        # Image holder.
        with col_1[0]:
            st.image(photos[st.session_state.idx], use_column_width=True)

            st.button('Previous', on_click=view_previous)
            st.button('Next', on_click=view_next)

        # Json holder
        with col_1[1]:
            json_file = f'{photos[st.session_state.idx]}.json'

            # Convert json file to a python dict.
            with open(json_file) as json_file:
                data = json.load(json_file)
            st.json(data, expanded=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### Output

[image]

##### The images and json files are located in image folder

```
PS F:\Project\mystreamlit\image> ls

    Directory: F:\Project\mystreamlit\image

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---          2022-11-27    18:03         424100 bailey-zindel-NRQV-hBF10M-unsplash.jpg        
-a---          2022-11-27    18:03            952 bailey-zindel-NRQV-hBF10M-unsplash.jpg.json   
-a---          2022-11-27    18:03         166843 ken-cheung-KonWFWUaAuk-unsplash.jpg
-a---          2022-11-27    18:03            949 ken-cheung-KonWFWUaAuk-unsplash.jpg.json      
-a---          2022-11-27    18:03         647469 pietro-de-grandi-T7K4aEPoGGk-unsplash.jpg     
-a---          2022-11-27    18:03            955 pietro-de-grandi-T7K4aEPoGGk-unsplash.jpg.json
```

##### Streamlit python script location

```
F:\Project\mystreamlit\photo_viewer.py
```

##### Command line

```
(venv) PS F:\Project\mystreamlit> streamlit run photo_viewer.py
```